# Having trouble translating the (+) operator from Oracle SQL to MS SQL in this query

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, join

I'm working on a project that involves taking a number of views that were written in Oracle and translating for use in MS SQL Server. I understand that the '(+)' operator was used in Oracle as left outer join, but for some reason with this particular query I can't seem to figure out how to adapt the join for MS SQL.

```
select
  M.THIS,
  M.THAT,
  M.ORANOTHER,
  sum(coalesce(M.ME, 0)) ME,
  sum(coalesce(M.YOU, 0)) YOU,
  sum(coalesce(M.THEM, 0)) THEM,
  sum(coalesce(M.US, 0)) US,
  sum(coalesce(M.THEY, 0)) THEY,
  sum(coalesce(M.HIM, 0)) HIM,
  E.EVERYONE,
  sum(coalesce(M.HER, 0)) HER,
  sum(coalesce(M.ITS, 0)) ITS
from THIS_IS_A_VIEW M
  left outer join THIS_IS_A_TABLE E
    on (
      M.FISH_ID = E.FLOUNDER
      and M.TUNA = E.TUNA
    )
where 'FISH IDS' = E.GILL_ID (+)
group by M.THIS, M.THAT, M.ORANOTHER, E.FISH_VALUE
```

Comment: `where 'FISH IDS' = E.GILL_ID (+)` --> `and 'FISH IDS' = E.GILL_ID`

Comment: @TheImpaler - that would effectively transform the join of THIS_IS_A_TABLE into an inner join, because now THIS_IS_A_TABLE.GILL_ID would have to equal 'FISH IDS' and would no longer be optional. This is a common problem with the "old-style" Oracle outer join notation.

Comment: @BobJarvis-СлаваУкраїні I don't think so. the `and` operator makes this predicate part of the `on` clause and, therefore, part of the `left outer join` clause.

Comment: Maybe I just misread what you were intending. I read it as "just drop the (+) from the WHERE clause, but leave the predicate *in* the WHERE clause, and all will be well". If you meant "move the predicate from the WHERE clause to the LOJ's ON clause and drop the (+)" then we can agree that's the right thing to do.

Answer (score 2):

The `(+)` simply means the condition belongs in the `ON` clause of the outer join:

```
FROM this_is_a_view m
LEFT OUTER JOIN this_is_a_table e ON e.flounder = m.fish_id
                                 AND e.tuna = m.tuna
                                 AND e.gill_id = 'FISH IDS'
```